# a program for transposing a matrix but in this program in printing result it has a bug

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

    int main(){
        int m,n,i,j,t;
        printf("in order enter line and column of matrix :");
        scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
        int a[n][m],b[m][n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                printf("a[%d][%d]= ",i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
              }
          }
        printf("first matrix:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                printf("%d    ",a[i][j]);
              }
              printf("\n\n");
          }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                b[j][i]=a[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf("transposed matrix:\n");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                printf("%d    ",b[j][i]);
              }
              printf("\n\n");
        }

      }
```

a program for transposing a matrix but in this program in printing result it has a bug, for example, this program for a Square matrix print first matrix

Comment: You print `b[j][i]` instead of `b[i][j]`.

Comment: @Eraklon and that's why is preferable to use var names like `row`, `col` instead of `i`, `j`

Comment: @Eraklon Thank you very much, but it's still a problem for 2 * 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've interchanged the row and column indices. Printing `b[i][j]` works fine. Even with non square matrices.

```
printf("transposed matrix:\n");
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("%d    ",b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
 }
```

Here is an example:

```
a[1][1]= 1
a[1][2]= 2
a[2][1]= 3
a[2][2]= 4
a[3][1]= 5
a[3][2]= 6
first matrix:
1    2    

3    4    

5    6    

transposed matrix:
1    3    5    

2    4    6
```